# How to select only specific time records for each day from C# DataTable using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, time

I am trying to select data from my datatable for the records of 21:00 to 05:00 for each day, and I am really struggling here i am stuck, can anyone please help me with this?

my datatable

```
     private DataTable mdata = new DataTable();
     mdata.Columns.Add("LogDate", typeof(string));
     mdata.Columns.Add("Readings", typeof(string));
     mdata.Columns.Add("Consumption", typeof(string));
```

Data in mdata table that comes from my sql select.

```
2021-05-29 00:00:00.0000000 2063561 3.39999999999418
2021-05-29 01:00:00.0000000 2063592 3.10000000000582
2021-05-29 02:00:00.0000000 2063622 3
2021-05-29 03:00:00.0000000 2063650 2.79999999998836
2021-05-29 04:00:00.0000000 2063686 3.60000000000582
2021-05-29 05:00:00.0000000 2063741 5.5
2021-05-29 06:00:00.0000000 2063844 10.3000000000175
2021-05-29 07:00:00.0000000 2063935 9.09999999997672
2021-05-29 08:00:00.0000000 2064018 8.30000000001746
2021-05-29 09:00:00.0000000 2064128 11
2021-05-29 10:00:00.0000000 2064220 9.19999999998254
2021-05-29 11:00:00.0000000 2064279 5.90000000002328
2021-05-29 12:00:00.0000000 2064363 8.39999999999418
2021-05-29 13:00:00.0000000 2064439 7.60000000000582
2021-05-29 14:00:00.0000000 2064506 6.69999999998254
2021-05-29 15:00:00.0000000 2064567 6.10000000000582
2021-05-29 16:00:00.0000000 2064633 6.60000000000582
2021-05-29 17:00:00.0000000 2064707 7.39999999999418
2021-05-29 18:00:00.0000000 2064777 7
2021-05-29 19:00:00.0000000 2064856 7.89999999999418
2021-05-29 20:00:00.0000000 2064916 6
2021-05-29 21:00:00.0000000 2064969 5.30000000001746
2021-05-29 22:00:00.0000000 2065005 3.59999999997672
2021-05-29 23:00:00.0000000 2065033 2.80000000001746
2021-05-30 00:00:00.0000000 2065057 2.39999999999418
2021-05-30 01:00:00.0000000 2065083 2.60000000000582
2021-05-30 02:00:00.0000000 2065108 2.5
2021-05-30 03:00:00.0000000 2065135 2.69999999998254
2021-05-30 04:00:00.0000000 2065193 5.80000000001746
2021-05-30 05:00:00.0000000 2065241 4.79999999998836
2021-05-30 06:00:00.0000000 2065320 7.89999999999418
2021-05-30 07:00:00.0000000 2065418 9.80000000001746
2021-05-30 08:00:00.0000000 2065497 7.89999999999418
2021-05-30 09:00:00.0000000 2065600 10.2999999999884
2021-05-30 10:00:00.0000000 2065691 9.10000000000582
2021-05-30 11:00:00.0000000 2065804 11.3000000000175
2021-05-30 12:00:00.0000000 2065904 10
2021-05-30 13:00:00.0000000 2065986 8.19999999998254
2021-05-30 14:00:00.0000000 2066097 11.1000000000058
2021-05-30 15:00:00.0000000 2066197 10
2021-05-30 16:00:00.0000000 2066285 8.79999999998836
2021-05-30 17:00:00.0000000 2066362 7.70000000001164
2021-05-30 18:00:00.0000000 2066454 9.20000000001164
2021-05-30 19:00:00.0000000 2066532 7.79999999998836
2021-05-30 20:00:00.0000000 2066594 6.20000000001164
2021-05-30 21:00:00.0000000 2066654 6
2021-05-30 22:00:00.0000000 2066710 5.59999999997672
2021-05-30 23:00:00.0000000 2066748 3.80000000001746
2021-05-31 00:00:00.0000000 2066777 2.89999999999418
2021-05-31 01:00:00.0000000 2066809 3.20000000001164
2021-05-31 02:00:00.0000000 2066842 3.29999999998836
2021-05-31 03:00:00.0000000 2066886 4.39999999999418
2021-05-31 04:00:00.0000000 2066958 7.20000000001164
```

and my current select and grouping that gives all records

```
DataTable NightResult = mdata.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Logdate = Convert.ToDateTime(x["LogDate"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                            Consumption = Convert.ToDouble(x["Consumption"]),
                            Readings = Convert.ToDouble(x["Readings"])

                        }).Where(x => x)???  // I am stuck here please help me!!
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Logdate })
                        .Select(g =>
                        {
                            var r = nightdata.NewRow();

                            r["Day"] = g.First().Logdate;
                            r["Max"] = g.Max(c => c.Consumption);
                            r["Min"] = g.Min(d => d.Consumption);
                            r["Avg"] = g.Average(e => e.Consumption);

                            return r;
                        })
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```

I would like only the records between 21:00 and 05:00 for each day over multiple days but I am not sure how to apply the "where" in the select.

below is the result I am trying to get before the grouping is applied in the above code (prefer not to do in sql)

```
2021-05-29 00:00:00.0000000 2063561 3.39999999999418
2021-05-29 01:00:00.0000000 2063592 3.10000000000582
2021-05-29 02:00:00.0000000 2063622 3
2021-05-29 03:00:00.0000000 2063650 2.79999999998836
2021-05-29 04:00:00.0000000 2063686 3.60000000000582
2021-05-29 05:00:00.0000000 2063741 5.5
2021-05-29 21:00:00.0000000 2064969 5.30000000001746
2021-05-29 22:00:00.0000000 2065005 3.59999999997672
2021-05-29 23:00:00.0000000 2065033 2.80000000001746
2021-05-30 00:00:00.0000000 2065057 2.39999999999418
2021-05-30 01:00:00.0000000 2065083 2.60000000000582
2021-05-30 02:00:00.0000000 2065108 2.5
2021-05-30 03:00:00.0000000 2065135 2.69999999998254
2021-05-30 04:00:00.0000000 2065193 5.80000000001746
2021-05-30 05:00:00.0000000 2065241 4.79999999998836
2021-05-30 21:00:00.0000000 2066654 6
2021-05-30 22:00:00.0000000 2066710 5.59999999997672
2021-05-30 23:00:00.0000000 2066748 3.80000000001746
2021-05-31 00:00:00.0000000 2066777 2.89999999999418
2021-05-31 01:00:00.0000000 2066809 3.20000000001164
2021-05-31 02:00:00.0000000 2066842 3.29999999998836
2021-05-31 03:00:00.0000000 2066886 4.39999999999418
2021-05-31 04:00:00.0000000 2066958 7.20000000001164
```

I have tried google and tried figuring it out from a bunch of posts here on stackoverflow but I have come up empty

Comment: .Where(x=> x.Logdate.Hour <= 5 || x.Logdate.Hour >= 21)

Comment: Hi Kamiky thank you for helping with the where part, when i try it i get the following error" string does not contain defenition for "Hour", i am going to try and change the colum format to datetime hopefully it will fix the error

Comment: Thank you it works after changing the column to type datetime the data is correct by now my grouping does not work so group by day is not working anymore want the records for the day grouped based on my data

Comment: If it's now a DateTime you can group by Logdate.Date instead.

Comment: T.Schwarz thank you for the quick help its working 100% correctly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help everyone, by changing the code as follows from the suggestions it now works 100% just needed a second perspective and input! Again thank you!

```
 DataTable NightResult = mdata.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Logdate = Convert.ToDateTime(x["LogDate"]),
                            Consumption = Convert.ToDouble(x["Consumption"]),
                            Readings = Convert.ToDouble(x["Readings"])

                        }).Where(x => x.Logdate.Hour <= 5 || x.Logdate.Hour >= 21)
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Logdate.Date })
                        .Select(g =>
                        {
                            var r = nightdata.NewRow();

                            r["Day"] = g.FirstOrDefault().Logdate.ToString();
                            r["Max"] = g.Max(c => c.Consumption);
                            r["Min"] = g.Min(d => d.Consumption);
                            r["Avg"] = g.Average(e => e.Consumption);

                            return r;
                        })
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```